# Script for change a SESSION variable

Tags: php

What I want is that when executing a script I change a SESSION variable

In the example I give you, the SESSION variable does not change. It is always closed and could change to open enrollment.

'periodoinscripcion.php'

```
<?php 

session_start();


$inscripcioncerrada = "inscripcion.php"; // CLOSE
$inscripcionabierta = "registrar.php"; // OPEN

$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $inscripcioncerrada;


if (isset($_REQUEST["estado"])) {
$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $_REQUEST['estado']; 
}

?>
```

and 'periodosinscripcion_abrir_registro.php'

```
<script language="javascript">

    var nuevoEstado = '$inscripcionabierta'; 
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    xhr.open('POST', 'periodoinscripcion.php'); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    xhr.send(encodeURI('estado=' + nuevoEstado));

</script>
```

Comment: try using $_POST instead of $_REQUEST. Also you can `var_dump($_POST); exit;` to check what vars are actually being sent to the page

Comment: Even if this did work, it would store the string "$inscripcionabierta" in your session, not "registrar.php",

Comment: Possibly this `$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $_REQUEST['estado']; ` should be changed to this `$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $inscripcionabierta;`

Comment: deceze no it wouldn't

Comment: can you modify my code and show as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you structured php file this way but maybe this works out:

**js**

```
 var nuevoEstado = 'registrar'; 
 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

 xhr.open('POST', 'periodoinscripcion.php', true);
 var params = 'estado=' + nuevoEstado;
 xhr.open('POST', url, true);

 //Send the proper header information along with the request
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhr.send(params);
```

**php**

```
<?php 

session_start();


$inscripcioncerrada = "inscripcion.php"; // CLOSE
$inscripcionabierta = "registrar.php"; // OPEN

$_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $inscripcioncerrada;


if (isset($_POST["estado"])) {
   $_SESSION['estadoInscripcion'] = $_POST['estado']; 
}
```

?>